# Stop AUCTeX from automatically adding style based on filename

Tags: auctex

If I try to create a LaTeX file named notes.tex, AUCTeX automatically adds the style "notes" and runs the style hook for "notes". This creates a bunch of environments in `LaTeX-environment-list` that conflict with my custom environments. Is there a way to prevent AUCTeX from automatically applying this style?

Alternatively, is there a way to remove a style hook?

Comment: Does this happen for all LaTeX files, or just when you use the name `notes.tex`?

Comment: It's when I use the name notes.tex. More generally, it seems to be when I use files whose name matches something in /var/lib/auctex/emacs/

For example, there's a file in there named postnotes.elc, and if I make a file named postnotes.tex, then AUCTeX gives is the style "postnotes"

Comment: When you create/open your .tex file, what's the value of `TeX-auto-save` in that buffer?

Comment: ```TeX-auto-save``` is nil

Comment: That's puzzling.  I wonder how that `notes.el` was generated.  AUCTeX itself doesn't contain a `notes.el`, as you can see [here](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/auctex.git/tree/style).  Maybe you've generated that last time you created another `notes.tex`?  In that case, you can probably remove that .el file.

Comment: I'm running debian, and the auctex package includes a file update-auctex-elisp, which apparently runs automatically whenever new style files are installed. One of the other debian packages installed a notes.sty file, which I guess triggered the creation of this notes.elc file. What I would prefer is that AUCTeX not apply a style based on the name of the TeX file, but I'm not sure there's a way to change that behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I think you have 2 possibilities then: 1) Ask Debian people if it's possible to disable their `update-auctex-elisp` script, or 2) Remove the target directory of that script from `TeX-style-path` as suggested below in the answer.  Personally, I think it's not a good choice to run `TeX-auto-generate-global` and such on a regular basis, but that's only me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is part of AucTeX's customization features. It's explained [in the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Automatic.html). I don't understand all the details, but it appears to include applying styles for files when the filename (in your case `notes.tex`) matches an AucTeX style file (i.e., `notes.elc`).

There doesn't appear to be a way to turn it off. However, you can customize the variable `TeX-style-path`, removing the directory containing the style files you don't want to use.

Someone else may be able to provide more complete help!